# ReentrantMutexGuard borrow_mut getting blocked

Tags: rust, mutex

Can somebody explain why my code panics when `borrow_mut()` is executed on a `ReentrantMutexGuard`. This is my code

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::cell::RefCell;

use parking_lot::ReentrantMutex;

#[derive(Default)]
struct InnerData {
    ia: i32,
    ib: i32,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct OuterData {
    oa: i32,
    ob: ReentrantMutex<RefCell<InnerData>>,
}

impl OuterData {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("fn foo begin");
        let mut b_mg = self.ob.lock();
        let mut b_data = b_mg.borrow_mut();
        println!("after acquiring lock");
        if b_data.ia == 3 {
            b_data.ib = 5;
        }
        println!("fn foo end");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut outer_data: OuterData = Default::default();
    let mut b_mg = outer_data.ob.lock();
    let mut b_data = b_mg.borrow_mut();
    b_data.ia = 3;

    if b_data.ia == 3 {
        outer_data.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "getting stuck" it seems to me this example panics because you try to borrow the same thing mutably twice. You cannot do that in Rust ever, a `ReentrantMutex` does not change the fact that references have to follow the aliasing rules.

Comment: @cafce25 My bad. You're correct. how do I get around this issue? Can you help me here

Comment: Drop `b_data` before you try to `borrow_mut` again.

Comment: is it possible without dropping the guard, because that might result in inconsistency. See my updated code

Comment: No, if by guard you mean the `RefMut` returned by `borrow_mut` because the guard holds a mutable reference and you **can't** have two mutable references to the same memory location in Rust, **ever**. You don't have to drop the mutexes guard though.

Comment: @Harry what do you by "may result in inconsistency"? Its not clear from the code because it doesn't indicate what invariants or behavior you need to preserve.

Comment: I'm just trying to imitate this C++ code https://godbolt.org/z/zM4xd8sqn

Comment: @cafce25 ok got it. I just need to drop the `RefMut` right? before `foo` method is called inside `main`

Comment: At that time, you may use a simple non-reentrant mutex and just drop the guard.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman wouldn't that let another thread take the guard in the mean time? Obviously doesn't matter in this single threaded example though.

Comment: Yes, it would, but does it matter? Most of the times it does not.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments: the reentrant mutex will grant you immutable access the inner value in a child scope while a parent scope holds the lock, but the `RefCell` will *not* allow mutable access to its value while the parent scope's `RefMut` is still alive in order to abide by Rust's referential guarantees.

Fortunately, you do not need to drop the lock guard, but you will need to drop the `RefMut` in order to release its exclusive hold on the data before calling a nested function that may want to access it. In your code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut outer_data: OuterData = Default::default();
    let mut b_mg = outer_data.ob.lock();
    let mut b_data = b_mg.borrow_mut();
    b_data.ia = 3;

    drop(b_data); // <----------------
    outer_data.foo();
}
```

Or some variation. You may want to better encapsulate your interior mutability (so as to limit how long `RefMut`s are active) to better avoid this issue.